# Add 2 list of floats together

Tags: python

How do i Add 2 lists that both have floats in them. Like how do I actually add the numbers?

Ive tried using
sum(list1, list2) but that did not work
I've also tried
list1+list2 but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please also add an example for input and expected output.

Comment: list1+list2 will actually add the lists

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a time for a list comprehension.

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
b = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]

[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Or for functional programming.

```
import operator
map(operator.add, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The zip method will do. It will combine all elements of a particular index. And since all of them are floating points, just add the values

```
l1=[1.5,3.2,5.0,3.5]
l2=[8.5,4.7,2.5,7.6]
l3=[i+j for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
print(l3)
```

Comment: Is this not the same thing as the other answer?